# How to generate text in dotted font in ITEXT?

Tags: java, itext

I want to generate worksheet as mentioned in link given below. http://www.softschools.com/handwriting/practice/ I am having problem in generating dotted font against given input. I want to to do this in itext jar, So can somebody guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom fonts to write your PDF with iText.

1. You would have to get the custom font you are looking for (I guess this is what your were referring to: http://www.dafont.com/kg-primary-dots.font)
2. I tried to write a quick and dirty code to create a line with the custom font in a PDF:

*Important: Please check and verify the end user agreement of the custom fonts being used for personal and commercial purposes*

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Document document = new Document();
        try {
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(
                    "C:/users/XY/desktop/XY/Dotted.pdf"));

            document.open();

            String text = "The test file for Kids";
            Font font = new Font(BaseFont.createFont("C:/Workspace/kg_primary_dots/KGPrimaryDotsLined.ttf",
                    BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED), 72, Font.NORMAL);

            Paragraph para = new Paragraph(text, font);

            document.add(para);
        } catch (DocumentException de) {
            System.err.println(de.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }

        document.close();
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]