Draw a traceable text on graphics 2D
I want to teach my kids to write numbers, thus I thought of drawing traceable letters to Graphics2D
I have tried the following approach
float[] textDash  = {15.0f};
g2d.setFont(g2d.getFont().deriveFont(400f));
metrics = g2d.getFontMetrics(g2d.getFont());
String numberString = "3";
BasicStroke dashedStroke = new BasicStroke(5f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT, BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER, 10.0f, textDash, 0.0f);
FontRenderContext frc = g2d.getFontRenderContext();
GlyphVector gv = g2d.getFont().createGlyphVector(frc, numberString);
Shape numberStringOutline = gv.getOutline();
AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(30, 200);
numberStringOutline = at.createTransformedShape(numberStringOutline);
numberStringOutline = dashedStroke.createStrokedShape(numberStringOutline);
g2d.fill(numberStringOutline);

Unfortunately this causes the outline to be dashed

I am trying to make a solid line to trace number 3 like one would see in tracing books, instead of an outline like you see.
Any advice on how to modify it so that I get a full number to trace instead of the outline?

Surely you'd be getting nearer to allowing your children to trace that 3 if you just called drawString with the correct coordinates?

I would do something like @MadProgrammer does here using an image like this Put g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5f)); into mouseDragged

Draw string simply draws a string that's solid and not dashed. It's not traceable.

@g00se Ah I finally understood what you said from the explanation you provided. I intend to print what I draw on the Graphics2D, and have them trace it with the pen.

The following might be a useful alternative https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039498/how-to-generate-text-in-dotted-font-in-itext

I suspect that you're running in the wrong direction. I wouldn't try and use the Font workflow, instead, I'd try and create the shapes yourself.  This could be done by either creating or finding a SVG source which had a "core" path (not outline) and then doing something like this to convert it to a Shape, this way you don't run into weird font scaling issues and have a lot more control

Actually using Font is probably the easiest way to get numbers to trace. The reason I used an image was that was at 'the bottom' of MadProgrammer's painting routine to which I've linked and it was the painting bit I wanted to show. What you can do is to combine showing the numbers via Font with painting (tracing on top of them)

@g00se But, what I think the OP is trying to do, is apply a custom stroke to the text rendering, so you'd get a dashed line through the "core" of the text, not it's outline, so, no, I don't think that's achievable via the Font and Graphics workflows

Well I thought that the idea was to have the kids trace on top of an existing digit. But let's await clarification

@g00se Based on the available information, the OP want's to start with a "dashed" line which the user can then trace, rather then having a solid line.  I've not been able to find away to get the "chord" path of the font, based on what little I know, I don't think that's how fonts work

Perhaps you're right. I think what is required is a single dashed line. So as you hinted, generating Paths might be the way to go

@MadProgrammer correct. That’s not how fonts work. There’s a reason why these kind of fonts are literally called “outline fonts”. The ordinary appearance is solid, because the outline is filled. That’s what Graphics2D’s fill method does. But by passing the result of createStrokedShape to fill, the OP emulated a call to the draw method.

My delirium tremens efforts with what I suggested (my 2nd). (This will probably be deleted)

Thanks to MadProgrammer.
Simple improvements would be a button to remove the template and to show (and maybe save) your childrens' efforts alone
In the meantime, this is an alternate look with Batik:

